# IUPAC nomenclature

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, stereochemistry, carbonyl-compounds

What is the IUPAC name of the following compound?

[image]

Comment: The preferred IUPAC name is (5  _E_)-_N_-(prop-2-en-1-yl)oct-5-enamide. Please add details to isolate your problem and to narrow the answer set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*E*)-N-allyloct-5-enamide

Start by looking for the longest continuous carbon chain. That's 8 carbons giving you the oct-.

On that chain, theres an alkene at the 5 position, and an amide at the end, giving the 5-enamide. You might also write this as 5-en-1-amide, though it is implied.

The geometry of the alkene as being *(E)* always goes to the front of the string, as would any R or S declarations. In this case, (E) is unambiguous, but in cases where multiple points of geometry exist, you would define geometry or stereochemistry along with position (5R),(3E) etc.

So, thus far you have *E*-oct-5-enamide. You now need to describe the other group bound to nitrogen on the amide, this is an allyl group, providing you with the full name (*E*)-N-allyloct-5-enamide.